# Not Extracting data from Json Object in zend php

Tags: json, post, zend-framework2, decode

I am sending this `json` data by PostMan:

```
{
    'id':10,
    'fname':'abc',
    'lname':'xyz'
}
```

On the  server side I receive the data by using:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$rawBody = $request->getContent();
```

`$rawBody` variable is of type string.
So how can I get those parameters...?

Comment: you should add more code to get better answer. is it GET or POST resquest? are you expecting dat in controller? is your controller extends AbstractRestfulController or extends AbstractRestfulController ?

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode($rawBody);` should work but I'd rather suggest:

```
\Zend\Json\Json::decode($rawBody);
```

or

```
$data = $request->getPost()->toArray();
```

*This is very basic stuff, you should be able to find this easily with Google.*

Answer (score 0):

thnx decoding solve the problem
I got it..

```
public function createAction()
{
$user=new User();
$request=$this->getRequest();
$rawBody=$request->getContent();
$u=\Zend\Json\Json::decode($rawBody);
$user->fname=$u->fname;
$user->lname=$u->lname;
$this->getUsersTable()->createUser($user);
return new JsonModel(array($user));
```

it was also a Json syntax error,double qoute resolve the error
    `{
    "id":10,
    "fname":"abc",
    "lname":"xyz"
    }`